# How value of a string variable can used to pick some existing variable having name as this string value?

Tags: python, dataframe, variables

Let us say, I have one Data Frame 'data_df' with 3 columns as shown below:

[image]

And, I have some additional variables named

**country** = 'India'

**state** = 'Madhya Pradesh'

**city** = 'Bhopal'

**var_name** = 'country'

```
print(df[var_name].iloc[0]) # prints 'India'
print(var_name)             # prints 'country'

**But I want to use this variable var_name and through some way, I should be able to get the value of the 'country' variable which is 'India'**
```

I hope you understood my question. If you have any doubt please ping in the comments. I want to know how can we do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically it can be done by manipulating symbol table, but it is a very bad idea. The right way to do it is to store your values in a dict rather than in separate variables:

```
d = {'country': 'India", 'state': 'Madhya Pradesh', 'city': 'Bhopal'}
```

and then you can refer to it by `d[var_name]`.

Comment: Yes, I knew that it is not a good way, but wanted to know how to solve these kind of cases. Thanks for your reply. Understood.

Comment: So, you **could** refer to `globals()[var_name]` - but you should not.

Comment: yes. this feature is answering my question, but some how making the things complicated.